405 Method Not Allowed : GET not allowed
I am building a simple bus reservation web app with Java 21 for backend . I keep getting error 405 Method Not Allowed ( GET not supported ) , This is my current code and i test with postman
BUS CONTROLLER
package com.example.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.DTO.BusDTO;
import com.example.Service.BusService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/buses")
public class BusController {

    @Autowired
    private BusService busService;

    // GET: Retrieve all buses
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<BusDTO>> getAllBuses() {
        List<BusDTO> buses = busService.getAllBuses();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(buses);
    }

    // GET: Retrieve a specific bus by ID
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<BusDTO> getBusById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        BusDTO bus = busService.getBusById(id);
        if (bus != null) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(bus);
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }
    }

    // POST: Add a new bus
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<BusDTO> createBus(@RequestBody BusDTO busDTO) {
        BusDTO createdBus = busService.addBus(busDTO);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(createdBus);
    }

    // Optional Test Endpoint
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public ResponseEntity<String> testEndpoint() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Test endpoint is working!");
    }
}


BUS DTO
package com.example.DTO;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Positive;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Size;

public class BusDTO {

    private Long busNr;

    @NotNull(message = "Model cannot be null")
    @Size(max = 100, message = "Model name cannot exceed 100 characters")
    @JsonProperty("modell")
    private String modell;

    @NotNull(message = "Availability status cannot be null")
    @JsonProperty("bereit")
    private Boolean bereit;

    @NotNull(message = "Number of seats cannot be null")
    @Positive(message = "Number of seats must be positive")
    @JsonProperty("sitzAnz")
    private Integer sitzAnz;

    // Getters and Setters
    public Long getBusNr() {
        return busNr;
    }

    public void setBusNr(Long busNr) {
        this.busNr = busNr;
    }

    public String getModell() {
        return modell;
    }

    public void setModell(String modell) {
        this.modell = modell;
    }

    public Boolean getBereit() {
        return bereit;
    }

    public void setBereit(Boolean bereit) {
        this.bereit = bereit;
    }

    public Integer getSitzAnz() {
        return sitzAnz;
    }

    public void setSitzAnz(Integer sitzAnz) {
        this.sitzAnz = sitzAnz;
    }
}


BUS ENTITY
package com.example.Entity;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;


@Entity
public class Bus {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long busNr;
    private String modell;
    private boolean bereit;
    private int sitzAnz;

    // Getters und Setters
    public Long getBusNr() {
        return busNr;
    }

    public void setBusNr(Long busNr) {
        this.busNr = busNr;
    }

    public String getModell() {
        return modell;
    }

    public void setModell(String modell) {
        this.modell = modell;
    }

    public boolean isBereit() {
        return bereit;
    }

    public void setBereit(boolean bereit) {
        this.bereit = bereit;
    }

    public int getSitzAnz() {
        return sitzAnz;
    }

    public void setSitzAnz(int sitzAnz) {
        this.sitzAnz = sitzAnz;
    }
}


BUSSERVICE
package com.example.Service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.DTO.BusDTO;
import com.example.Entity.Bus;
import com.example.repository.BusRepository;

@Service
public class BusService {

    @Autowired
    private BusRepository busRepository;

    public BusDTO addBus(BusDTO busDTO) {
        Bus bus = new Bus();
        bus.setModell(busDTO.getModell());
        bus.setBereit(busDTO.getBereit());
        bus.setSitzAnz(busDTO.getSitzAnz());

        bus = busRepository.save(bus);

        BusDTO savedDTO = new BusDTO();
        savedDTO.setBusNr(bus.getBusNr());
        savedDTO.setModell(bus.getModell());
        savedDTO.setBereit(bus.isBereit());
        savedDTO.setSitzAnz(bus.getSitzAnz());
        return savedDTO;
    }

    public List<BusDTO> getAllBuses() {
        return busRepository.findAll()
                .stream()
                .map(bus -> {
                    BusDTO dto = new BusDTO();
                    dto.setBusNr(bus.getBusNr());
                    dto.setModell(bus.getModell());
                    dto.setBereit(bus.isBereit());
                    dto.setSitzAnz(bus.getSitzAnz());
                    return dto;
                })
                .toList();
    }

    public BusDTO getBusById(Long id) {
        return busRepository.findById(id)
                .map(bus -> {
                    BusDTO dto = new BusDTO();
                    dto.setBusNr(bus.getBusNr());
                    dto.setModell(bus.getModell());
                    dto.setBereit(bus.isBereit());
                    dto.setSitzAnz(bus.getSitzAnz());
                    return dto;
                })
                .orElse(null);
    }
}


Docker-compose.yml
version: "3.8"

services:
  # MySQL service for Kunden
  kunden-db:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: kunden-db
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: kundenDB
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root-new
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    volumes:
      - kunden-db-data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./DB/conf/kunden.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/kunden.sql
    networks:
      - app-network

  # MySQL service for Fahrzeuge
  fahrzeug-db:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: fahrzeug-db
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: fahrzeugDB
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root-new
    ports:
      - "3308:3306"
    volumes:
      - fahrzeug-db-data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./DB/conf/fahrzeug.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/fahrzeug.sql
    networks:
      - app-network

  # Spring Boot application
  spring-boot-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: spring-boot-app
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://fahrzeug-db:3306/fahrzeugDB
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: backend
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: backend-pass
      SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO: update
    ports:
      - "8082:8080"
    depends_on:
      - fahrzeug-db
      - kunden-db
    networks:
      - app-network

volumes:
  kunden-db-data:
  fahrzeug-db-data:

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge


DATABASE
USE fahrzeugDB;

CREATE TABLE fahrzeug (
    fahrzeugNr INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    modell VARCHAR(100),
    bereit BOOLEAN,
    sitzAnz INT
) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;

create user 'backend' identified by 'backend-pass';
grant select, insert, delete, update on fahrzeug to 'backend';

2024-11-20T11:29:35.651Z  WARN 1 --- [ws2024_team_f] [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "create table bus (bus_nr bigint not null auto_increment, bereit bit not null, modell varchar(255), sitz_anz integer not null, primary key (bus_nr)) engine=InnoDB" via JDBC [CREATE command denied to user 'backend'@'172.19.0.4' for table 'bus']

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table bus (bus_nr bigint not null auto_increment, bereit bit not null, modell varchar(255), sitz_anz integer not null, primary key (bus_nr)) engine=InnoDB" via JDBC [CREATE command denied to user 'backend'@'172.19.0.4' for table 'bus']
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar!/:6.5.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:583) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar!/:6.5.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:523) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar!/:6.5.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:323) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar!/:6.5.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:80) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar!/:6.5.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:240) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar!/:6.5.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar!/:6.5.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:280) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar!/:6.5.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.lambda$process$5(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar!/:6.5.3.Final]
at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1429) ~[na:na]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:141) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar!/:6.5.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryObserverForSchemaExport.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverForSchemaExport.java:37) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar!/:6.5.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryObserverChain.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverChain.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar!/:6.5.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:322) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar!/:6.5.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:457) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar!/:6.5.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1506) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar!/:6.5.3.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.1.14.jar!/:6.1.14]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-6.1.14.jar!/:6.1.14]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.1.14.jar!/:6.1.14]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.1.14.jar!/:6.1.14]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:366) ~[spring-orm-6.1.14.jar!/:6.1.14]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar!/:6.1.14]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1802) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar!/:6.1.14]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar!/:6.1.14]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar!/:6.1.14]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar!/:6.1.14]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar!/:6.1.14]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar!/:6.1.14]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar!/:6.1.14]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:954) ~[spring-context-6.1.14.jar!/:6.1.14]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:625) ~[spring-context-6.1.14.jar!/:6.1.14]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.3.5.jar!/:3.3.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.3.5.jar!/:3.3.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.3.5.jar!/:3.3.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) ~[spring-boot-3.3.5.jar!/:3.3.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.3.5.jar!/:3.3.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.3.5.jar!/:3.3.5]
at com.example.Ws2024TeamFApplication.main(Ws2024TeamFApplication.java:11) ~[!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:102) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:64) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:40) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: CREATE command denied to user 'backend'@'172.19.0.4' for table 'bus'
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:121) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar!/:8.3.0]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar!/:8.3.0]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:770) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar!/:8.3.0]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:653) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar!/:8.3.0]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar!/:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar!/:na]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:80) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar!/:6.5.3.Final]
... 42 common frames omitted
2024-11-20T11:29:35.659Z  INFO 1 --- [ws2024_team_f] [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-11-20T11:29:36.060Z  WARN 1 --- [ws2024_team_f] [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2024-11-20T11:29:36.471Z  WARN 1 --- [ws2024_team_f] [           main] .s.s.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration :
Using generated security password: 25e64de9-731e-495b-a589-34cb7c057fe1
This generated password is for development use only. Your security configuration must be updated before running your application in production.
2024-11-20T11:29:36.496Z  INFO 1 --- [ws2024_team_f] [           main] r$InitializeUserDetailsManagerConfigurer : Global AuthenticationManager configured with UserDetailsService bean with name inMemoryUserDetailsManager
2024-11-20T11:29:36.703Z  INFO 1 --- [ws2024_team_f] [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port 8080 (http) with context path '/'
2024-11-20T11:29:36.732Z  INFO 1 --- [ws2024_team_f] [           main] com.example.Ws2024TeamFApplication       : Started Ws2024TeamFApplication in 4.901 seconds (process running for 5.466)
2024-11-20T11:30:20.500Z  INFO 1 --- [ws2024_team_f] [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-11-20T11:30:20.501Z  INFO 1 --- [ws2024_team_f] [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-11-20T11:30:20.504Z  INFO 1 --- [ws2024_team_f] [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 3 ms
2024-11-20T11:30:20.716Z  WARN 1 --- [ws2024_team_f] [nio-8080-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' is not supported]
I kept trying to adjust the controller and service class to Support GET method but the same error is emerging

How are you hitting the API ?

I am using Postman with the following Details :
Method : GET
localhost:8082/api/buses
Basic Authorization with user/passkey

Please confirm if you cleaned and rebuilt your docker image after making the change. As of current state, your code should work.
Infact I would advise you to run your application outside the container and check if its working.
You can remove its relation with database and try again. Keep trying till you get a very simple code which is still not working.

Method not allowed, ideally means you are trying to invoke the correct endpoint, however with a wrong REST Action type, for e.g. hitting the right endpoint of GET but selecting POST or any other from postman , just ensure that is not the case

provide the snippet of the error that you are getting on console if u are using spring security use logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG for debugging

i always clean and rebuild docker image after any changes , and i tried to change the endpoint of POST and GET several times

the debugging basically says :
1-Error: Communications link failure / but my ports are correct and both the springboot app and Database are on the same network
2-Error: CREATE command denied to user 'backend'@'%' for table 'bus'


Method Not Allowed basically comes when you have different method in
Controller and accessing using different method in URL. So make sure
that whatever method you are using in endpoint the same method should
be use in URL.

        @RestController
        @RequestMapping("/api/buses")
        public class BusController {
        
            @GetMapping
            public ResponseEntity<List<BusDTO>> getAllBuses() {
                List<BusDTO> buses = busService.getAllBuses();
                return ResponseEntity.ok(buses);
            }
        }
        
        Test with Postman :
        <base_url>/api/buses => Make sure above endpoint should be used with GET mapping method only

